# What the pivot operation of the Simplex algorithm actually does?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I am reading about the Simplex algorithm and I don't understand how to pivot operation is able to increase the objective function if all it does is interchanging one variable with another and then substituting the variable in all other equations.

Answer (score 0):

A simplex iteration is not only a basis change but also doing a step (step size is limited by the ratio-test).